# symfony2 - Talend ETL in a symfony website

Tags: symfony, etl

I need to develop a compare prices application with symfony ,ETL,ESB ...application which import CSV files,and store content in database (MySQL). I started reading about Talend (an open source ETL) but I have a little trouble finding good tutorials that teach the implementation of this ETL in my website.
So any ideas.

Thank you .

Answer (score -1):

voilà un bon tutoriel "Talend Open Studio" ;)
http://www.pfl-cepia.inra.fr/uploads/gdp_docs/TalendOpenStudio_Studio_UG_40b_FR.pdf

Comment: Thankk you i have alreadu this tutorial ...but i  want to know how tu use it with symfony ..what i mean is how to use talend (etl) in symfony to import differnet file (csv,xml,json....)into database and use this data